# How can we differentiate LAN and wireless data card network connection using NLM (NetworkListManager) API's?

Tags: winapi, networking, nlm

I am working with NLM API's (windows). I have a LAN connection and Wireless data card connection. I am enumerating the networks available.

Code:

```
HRESULT hr;
VARIANT_BOOL pBool1, pBool2;
IEnumNetworks *pEnumNetworks;
INetwork *pNetwork;


hr = pNetwork->get_IsConnected(&pBool1);

hr = pNetwork->get_IsConnectedToInternet(&pBool2);
```

I have both LAN and Wireless data card connected.

For LAN `pBool1` value is True and `pBool2` value is False.

For Wireless Data card both `pBool1` and `pBool2` values are true.

When I disconnect the wireless data card, For LAN `pBool2` value is false, though i am able to access Internet while i am in LAN connection ?? Any idea why this value is False?

How can we differentiate LAN and wireless data card network connection using NLM (NetworkListManager) API's?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the adapter type and then check the connectivity. Also implement wireless data card native api callback to listen to changes.